# Add same form element below by clicking add button. using Angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, dynamic-forms

I have a form1 and a add button. The thing I want is to add same form as form2 below form1 on clinking add button. As I am new to Angular Js it will be very helpful if someone can help me out.
[image: Current Output]

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <header class="panel-heading">
    <h5 class="panel-title" style="padding-left: 1.5rem;">
      <b>APPLICANTS</b>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right " type="button" value="Add" />
    </h5>
    <hr>
  </header>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model="txtFullName">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Nationality</label>
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model="txtNationality">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Pin Code</label>
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model="txtPincode">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">House No.</label>
            <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDefault" ng-model="txtHouseNo">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of applicants model objects, let's call it `applicantsArray`, where every object will represent a single applicant form.
You need to initialize this array with one model empty on page load.
Then you need to wrap your form with `ng-for` and iterate over every applicant model. So the n-th form will be binded with the n-th model in the `applicantsArray`.
Last step will be to push an empty applicant model to `applicantsArray` when 'Add' is clicked. Then a new model is added and the DOM will render additional form for the new model.